# Definition of ui-sref in Angular.js?

Tags: html, angularjs, definition, ui-sref

I've been having some trouble getting a decent explanation of what `ui-sref` is actually doing in angular.

In HTML `href` is **h**yperlink **ref**erence, so does `sref` mean **s**cript **ref**erence?

Answer (score 17):

`ui-sref` stands for UI-Router state reference. It's a way to change states/state params (as defined in using the `$stateProvider` in a config block using the ui.router module for AngularJS. You can read the [ui-sref documentation here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref).